# access a component property in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have three classes
Student.java

```
public class Student {
    long id;
    String name;
    Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {
    String houseNumber;
    String addrLine1;
    String addrLine2;
    String phone;

    public String getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }
    public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }
    public String getAddrLine1() {
        return addrLine1;
    }
    public void setAddrLine1(String addrLine1) {
        this.addrLine1 = addrLine1;
    }
    public String getAddrLine2() {
        return addrLine2;
    }
    public void setAddrLine2(String addrLine2) {
        this.addrLine2 = addrLine2;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Hibernate Mapping for Student.hbm.xml
Student.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Student" table="STUDENT">
<id name="id" type="long" column="ID"/>
  <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
  <component name="address" class="Address">
    <property name="houseNumber" column="HOUSE_NUMBER" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="addrLine1" column="ADDRLINE1"/>
    <property name="addrLine2" column="ADDRLINE2"/>
    <property name="phone" column="PHONE"/>
  </component>
</component>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to access the property houseNumber, phone using detached criteria
but when I try to get the property as address.phone
I get the errors as 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: phone of: Student

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because Student really does not have the "phone", which is a Address property.

The correct usage should be something like `session.createCriteria( Student.class ).add( Restrictions.eq( "address.phone", "myPhoneNumber" ) ).list()` for common criterias.

The version with DetachedCriteria is

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass( Student.class ).add(Restrictions.eq( "address.phone", "99999999" ) );
List students = criteria.getExecutableCriteria( session ).list();
```

Comment: The criteria is  getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(com.Student:this[ Subcriteria(address:)][phone = 99999999 ])))

Comment: Answer updated with DetachedCriteria version. I tested it with hibernate 3.6.7 and 4.2.7.

Comment: the DetachedCriteria is of version hibernate 3.2.0

Comment: The above version works even with Hibernate 3.2.0 for me. Have you tried it? Is the same error message?